# IONIC parse JSON

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a small school project application. I get data from an API like this :

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://nightee.dev/stores/' + position.coords.latitude + '/' + position.coords.longitude,
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.stores = response.data;
        console.log($scope.stores);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

and I want to populate it into a ion list

```
<ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left ng-repeat="store in stores" ui-sref="/store/{{store.url}}">
                <img ng-src="img/location-pin.svg" />
                <h2>{{store.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{store.distance}}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

But nothing displays on the view, do you have an idea why ? is my syntax wrong ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!

Comment: And console.log logs data okay?

Comment: It seems so http://imgur.com/8vb3IfA

Comment: Do you have closing `"` after `class="item-thumbnail-left` of this is just a typo?

Comment: It was a typo. I'm sooo dumb. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Haha, insidious typos.